# Контроллер тачпада и Asm

Tags: ассемблер, железо, ноутбук

Возможно ли в современных ноутбуках через DOS и Asm добраться до порта тачпада, чтобы напрямую считывать данные с него? 
Если да, то в какую сторону копать?
P.S. через 33h не предлагать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, в большинстве ноутбуков тачпад подсоединён как бы через внутренний последовательный порт ps/2.
 Получить доступ к данным возможно с помощью регистра данных через порт 60h.